# Rails Template Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently updated a controller from a plain

```
render :json => @something
```

to

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.html {
            redirect_to @something
          }
          format.json {
            puts "found json format"
            format.json { render json: @something, status: :created }
          }
        end
```

But, now I'm getting ActionView::MissingTemplate errors. My question is, if I use the respond_to do |format| block, am I required to use a template? What if I just want to return plain json?

Btw, the puts statement in the json respond_to block is being called successfully.

Comment: why do you need to `format.json` inside `format.json {}`? I think you need to call just `render..` inside the `format.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `puts` being called inside of your format.json block and the nesting of format.json inside of it's own block. Try removing both (as below).

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.html {
            redirect_to @something
          }
          format.json {
            puts "found json format"
            format.json { render json: @something, status: :created }
          }
        end
```

Try:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @something }
    format.json  { render json: @something, status: :created }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are telling that you accept HTML and JSON formats. Since your request comes from HTML you'll have the HTML template rendered.
If you want to return only JSON remove that line from your code. Also check the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) on `respond_to`.

Probably you already know it, but there's a guide on [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `format.json` part from within the json rendering block (you have an unnecessary block within your block):

```
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        redirect_to @something
      }
      format.json {
        render json: @something, status: :created
      }
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason your code is prompting an error it's because you have

```
format.json {
            format.json { render json:  @something , status: :created }
          }
```

You should have:

```
format.json {
           render json:  @something , status: :created
          }
```